# hostname changed without me changing anything

Tags: hostname

My hostname changed to "cpe-172-101-0-1.maine.res.rr.com systemd-resolved" without my consent on fedora 37.
When i type journalctl -u systemd-hostnamed.service

journalctl -xe entry is:

```
févr. 05 16:27:25 cpe-172-101-0-1.maine.res.rr.com systemd-hostnamed[18393]: Hostname set to <cpe-172-101-0-1.maine.res.rr.com> (transient)
févr. 05 16:27:55 cpe-172-101-0-1.maine.res.rr.com systemd[1]: systemd-hostnamed.service: Deactivated successfully.
févr. 05 16:32:51 cpe-172-101-0-1.maine.res.rr.com systemd[1]: Starting systemd-hostnamed.service - Hostname Service...
févr. 05 16:32:51 laptop-fedora systemd[1]: Started systemd-hostnamed.service - Hostname Service.
févr. 05 16:32:51 laptop-fedora systemd-hostnamed[18679]: Hostname set to <laptop-fedora> (transient)
```

How can this happen ?

Comment: I see "cpe-...." in your logs. are you connecting your laptop to a modem or something provide you with an IP address?

Comment: im connecting to an opnsense firewall which is connected to a 4G/LTE modem all through ethernet

Answer (score 1):

Fedora simplified the old install process and skips setting a hostname. As you can see, it is showing the transient hostname in both cases. Per the `hostnamectl` manpage, the transient hostname is a fallback received from the network configuration if there is no static hostname set.

You should manually set a hostname. This can be done by running `sudo hostnamectl hostname HOSTNAME` (where HOSTNAME is whatever you want it to be). This will update the static hostname and takes priority over transient ones, and will not change.

Comment: hi 
thanks. how can i check the process or get more infos about "the transient hostname is a fallback received from the network configuration" ?

Comment: You can check the man page for hostnamectl - https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/hostnamectl.html#

Comment: yes, they say "and the transient hostname which is a fallback value received from network configuration (e.g. "node12345678")"